# regex match sub-string before sequence of numbers

Tags: php, regex, string, pcre

I only want to get the - and space after - before the 4 numbers. I made the following regex to try and match these characters. `^(- )+?(?=\d{4})$`
if i try this regex on the number string below i get no matches.
- 7575

what am i doing wrong?
I quite am new to regex.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `?=` is a positive look ahead but does not match what's inside, try put de `$` inside it like `^(- )+?(\d{4}$)`

Comment: Why are you using this: `(- )+?`? Do you know what that means?  Do you want to match `- - - - - 1234` (multiple alternating occurrences of hyphen then space)?  Can you post a small list of sample inputs and your expected output?  (yes, I see that you have accepted an answer already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your actual regex does is :
`^(- )+?` => match a sequence of `-`
Which has to be followed by 4 digit `(?=\d{4})` without matching it
Then ending sentence `$`
So it's impossible.
You either , if you dont want to match the digit, have to put the end in the positive lookahead like
`^(- )+?(?=\d{4}$)`
Or remove the positive lookahead like
`^(- )+?\d{4}$`